# NGINX Reverse Proxy redirect settings

Tags: nginx, redirect, reverse-proxy, https

I have the following scenario:

```
      NGINX |                     | JavaEE
TERMINATING | -> REVERSE PROXY -> | Application
  SSL (443) |         HTTP        | Server
```

Reverse proxy is done by:

```
location /app/ {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header Host www.example.com;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://192.168.0.10:8080/app/;
}
```

The problem was that, all relative redirects done at application server (i.e. Location: /app/login) where being redirected to `http://www.example.com/app/login` instead of its https counterpart `https://www.example.com/app/login`.

So, to fix it, I added this to NGINX's location configuration:

```
proxy_redirect http://www.example.com/ https://www.example.com/;
```

And it started working without issues.

My question is: is it good practice to have such a redirect? Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Probably better way would be to fix your app to send correct redirect, but  it's quite good. That what `proxy_redirect` is intended for.